# how to use the force command with a type unsigned(n downto 0) in modelsim when simulating a VHDL file?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

When initializing inputs for a test, as I understand, you have to use the force command. For example to create a clock cycle, counting that the entity I'm simulating has an input named clock, which is of type std_logic, I would usually write

```
force clock 0 0, 1 1 -repeat 2
```

in thee terminal of modelsim
how can I do something similar but with the type unsigned(8 downto 0) for example?

Comment: why not simply create a testbench and drive the clock from there instead?

Comment: @Tricky I'm quite new to VHDL, so this is pretty much the only "quick"  way I've learned to test separate files.